# Burninate [changes]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[changes](/questions/tagged/changes) is a clear-cut meta tag. [The tag wiki says something to the effect that it has no clear-cut meaning.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/changes/info) It is seen on such questions as

- [Something to do with robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704910/made-changes-to-robots-txt-but-search-engines-still-say-description-not-availabl)
- [Facebook comment changes [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119400/non-threaded-comments-please-see-the-developer-roadmap-for-more-details-about-t)
- [Directory update notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732582/fast-way-of-detecting-directory-changes)
- [Database update stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723380/mysql-how-to-get-changes-of-last-update)
- [Auto-incrementing fields in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563581/increment-row-number-when-value-of-field-changes-in-oracle)
- [Integer range-check diffs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543977/check-if-any-values-have-changed-a-certain-amount)

And that's just the first page. Looks like burnination time.

[image: Official burninate-request image]

Comment: Perhaps [tag:modify], too?